# Optimizely: measure page impressions

Tags: pageviews, optimizely

I want to include a new link block on my pages. But before I activate it I want to test if it makes sense.

So following Optimizelys [Article on Pageview goals](https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/200090069-Pageview-goals) I set up a test to measure page view conversions. But obiously I am doing it wrong.

As a simplified example let's assume, **all** my pages have URLs of the following pattern: **www.mydomain.com/page_[0-9]+.htm**
(for example www.mydomain.com/page_123.htm).

And my new link will lead the user to another page of the above pattern.

The problem seems to be that Optimizely does not really count the number of pages visited, but instead counts the first visit already as a conversion (given that the URL pattern always matches).
**So both my test variations turn out the same results.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which seems to do the trick (although not being the perfect solution):

Using Javascript I append **#opt** (or whatever you like) to the links in question.

And the goal pattern is accordingly changed to **www.mydomain.com/page_[0-9]+.htm#opt**.

This way...

1. the first page the visitor visits will not be counted as a conversation (since #opt is missing)
2. all the other pages on the page won't be counted for the same reason
3. except the ones that are specifically targeted in my tested links.